# Start SQL Server Management Studio from command line with trusted connection

Tags: sql-server, ssl, ssms, self-signed-certificate

I have been using shortcuts for connections in SQL Server Management Studio for several years, but after installing Windows Server 2022 and Management Studio 20, I need to enable the option "trust certificate".

Initially the shortcut throws an error message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

But when I enable the trusted connection it is successful.

But the question now is: how to do that in the command line ? In a connection string one would use "Trusted_Connection=True" but how to do that in a SSMS shortcut....any thoughts about that ? I am using the -S and -E parameters but there is no command line parameter for using trusted connections.

PS: I tried using command line parameters for `SSMS.exe` but not successfully....

Comment: "Trusted Connection" is nothing to do with that error, it's "Trust Server Certificate". Why don't you just fix the problem to start with, by preferably getting a proper certificate for the server, or pinning the self-signed cert as trusted, or by disabling encryption? "Trust Server Certificate" is a bad option, it papers over the issue. The "Trusted Connection" option by the way is the `-E` option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I have to dive into that because a certificate for a database server is new to me. Will have to pass it to our IT dept. Thanks again!

Comment: For local connections it would be nice to have a switch to "Trust server certificate", like the checkbox that appears when you open SSMS manually.